# Converting GeoJSON point into polygon in React

Tags: geojson, convert, csv, sql-server, react

I have a JSON file of areas making polygon. I have saved those files in SQL Server database so i convert GeoJSON into CSV and import in my database and now i want to connect database with React.js.

Problem is when i import CSV the polygon is converted into points. i want to convert lat long point from database into polygon JSON in runtime and show in my React.js map. any solutions?